# How to overwrite compiled(?) script?

Tags: lua

If I create a simple lua script file:

test.lua

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local var = math.random(100)
print(var)
```

It will always print the same value when called, even though it really should be a new random value at each call.

My guess is that the script gets compiled(?) to for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local var = 82
print(var)
```

*(if 82 was the random value at first call)*


**What can I do to make sure that a new (?)bytecode gets compiled(?) each time I call the script, so that I can get a fresh random value at each execution of the script?**


*The reason I added the (?) is that I don't even know if scripts get compiled at all or what happens to them when they are called, but something like that is clearly happening since I get the same value all the time.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script is not being kept as bytecode, it's just that the same default random seed is used at every run. This has the effect you're seeing: you get the same "random" sequence every time you run your script.

You should initialize it by doing, for example

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```